# How can I create batch file to run a command?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I've writen this command line successfully:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:157286400
```

I want to create a batch file to execute this line.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new text document
2. Rename it "mybatfile.bat"
3. Press yes when prompted "If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?"
4. Right click on the bat file, "edit"
5. Put in your command:

> ```
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:157286400
> ```

Comment: U mean put it on the bat, without any add

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the command prompt you could type

```
copy con myfile.bat 
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:157286400
"press F-6"
```

then enjoy your bat file.

Is this not a setting you could change in a config file somewhere so it is permanent though?